Only one test running when selenium tests run in parallel using local thread
We are automating an application which support desktop and mobile browser, so we choose selenium, appium, java client, testNG. to reduce execution we implemented parallel test execution using TestNG and created local thread safe. when we run concurrently they run fine but when we run in parallel only one test will run and other tests will be idle.
I am sharing what work we did to achieve this parallel test execution , please help me to get fixed if requires any changes, really we got stuck at bottle neck.
code:
DriverManager Class File
  private static final ThreadLocal<RemoteWebDriver> threadLocalDriver = new ThreadLocal<>();

  public  static RemoteWebDriver getDriver() {
   return threadLocalDriver.get();
  }

  public static void setDriver(RemoteWebDriver driver) {
    if (Objects.nonNull(driver)) {
      threadLocalDriver.set(driver);
    }
  }

  public static void unload() {
    threadLocalDriver.remove();
  }
}```


DriverFactory class:
```public final class DriverFactory {
  public static synchronized RemoteWebDriver initializeMobileDriver(MobilePlatformName mobilePlatformName, String deviceName, String udid, Boolean isEmulator, Boolean headLessMode, String browserName,
                                                                   URL url) {
   RemoteWebDriver driver = null;
   switch (mobilePlatformName) {
     case ANDROID_WEB:
       driver = Drivers.createAndroidDriverForWeb(deviceName, browserName, udid,isEmulator, headLessMode,url);
       break;
     case IOS_WEB:
       break;
     default:
       throw new DriverInitializationException(
         "Please check the platform name");
   }
   DriverManager.setDriver(driver);
   return driver;
 }
 public static synchronized RemoteWebDriver initializeWebDriver(WebBrowserName browserName,Boolean isHeadless) {
    RemoteWebDriver driver = null;
    switch (browserName) {
      case CHROME
        driver = Drivers.createChromeDriver(isHeadless);
        break;
      case FIREFOX:
        driver = Drivers.createFirefoxDriver(isHeadless);
        break;
      default:
        throw new DriverInitializationException(
                "Please check the Browser name");
    }
    DriverManager.setDriver(driver);
    return driver;
  }

  public static void shutdownDriver( RemoteWebDriver driver) {
    if (Objects.nonNull(driver)) {
      try {
        if (driver instanceof AppiumDriver) {
          ((AppiumDriver) driver).quit();
        } else if (driver instanceof WebDriver) {
          ((WebDriver) driver).quit();
        }
      } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Error during driver shutdown: " + e.getMessage());
      } finally {
          unload();
      }
    }
  }
}```


BaseTest Class File:
```public class BaseTest {
  @BeforeClass(alwaysRun = true)
  @Parameters({"deviceName","platformType","browserName","environment"})
  public void setUp(String deviceName, String platformType,@Optional("chrome")String browserName,@Optional("qa") String environment) throws IOException,Exception {
    try {
        Boolean isMobile= (Boolean) deviceInfo.get("isMobile");
        Boolean isHeadLess = (Boolean) deviceInfo.get("isHeadless");
        if (Objects.isNull(DriverManager.getDriver())) {
            if (isMobile) {
                serverManager.startServer();
                deviceName = deviceInfo.getString("devicename");
                String avd = deviceInfo.getString("avd");
                String udid = deviceInfo.getString("udid");
                String platformVersion = deviceInfo.getString("platformVersion");
                Boolean isEmulator = (Boolean) deviceInfo.get("isEmulator");
                URL url = new ServerManager().getServer().getUrl();
                driver=DriverFactory.initializeMobileDriver(MobilePlatformName.valueOf(platformType.toUpperCase()), deviceName, udid, isEmulator, isHeadLess,browserName, url);
            } else {
                driver=DriverFactory.initializeWebDriver(WebBrowserName.valueOf(browserName.toUpperCase()), isHeadLess);
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Driver setup by Thread "+Thread.currentThread().getId()+" and Driver reference is : "+DriverManager.getDriver());
        driver= DriverManager.getDriver();
        driver.manage().deleteAllCookies();
    }catch (Exception ex){
        logException(ex);
    }

}```


Test Class:
```public class E2ETests extends BaseTest{
  public void TC_TestParallel() {
        try {
            String methodName = commonUtils.getCurrentMethodName();
            TestContextManager.setMethod(methodName);
            System.out.println("Driver setup by Thread "+Thread.currentThread().getId()+" and Driver reference is : "+ DriverManager.getDriver());

            NavigationPage navigationPage=new NavigationPage(driver, this);
            TestLoginPage loginPage=new TestLoginPage(driver);

            navigationPage.pageNavigation("/login","Login");
            loginPage.performYahooLogIn();

        }catch (Exception ex){
            logException(ex);
        }

    }

} ```

TestLoginPage:
```public class TestLoginPage extends BasePage {
  public TestLoginPage(RemoteWebDriver driver,BaseTest baseTest) throws InterruptedException {
        super(driver);
        this.driver=driver;
        this.baseTest=baseTest;
        PageFactory.initElements(driver, this);
        wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, Duration.ofSeconds(WAIT));
    }
    public void performYahooLogIn() throws InterruptedException {
      try {
            eleUsername.sendKeys("testuser@yahoomail.com");
            eleNextButton.click();
            driver.manage().timeouts().pageLoadTimeout(Duration.ofSeconds(WAIT));
            }catch (Exception ex){
                logException(ex);
            }
      }
}```

```public class NavigationPage extends BasePage{

    private static Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoginPage.class);
    ProjectConfig configuration = ConfigurationManager.config();
    ProjectConfig projectConfig;
    private JsonDataReader testDataJsonReader;
    private JsonDataReader commonDataJsonReader;
    BaseTest baseTest;
    RemoteWebDriver driver;

    public NavigationPage(RemoteWebDriver driver, BaseTest baseTest) throws InterruptedException {
        super(driver);
        this.driver=driver;
        this.baseTest=baseTest;
        PageFactory.initElements(driver, this);
        logger.info("Initializing the "+this.getClass().getSimpleName()+" elements");
    }

    public void pageNavigation(String urlFilePath) throws InterruptedException {
      try {
          String baseURL = TestEnvironment.getBaseUrl().trim();
          driver.get(baseURL+urlFilePath);
      }catch (Exception ex){
          System.out.println("An exception during page navigation: "+ex.getMessage());
      }
    }
}```


TestNG.xml
```<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "https://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd" >
<suite name="Parallel Tests" verbose="4" parallel="tests" thread-count="3">
<test name="Web chrome tests" enabled="true">
       <parameter name="deviceName" value="PCChrome" />
       <parameter name="platformType" value="mac" />
       <parameter name="browserName" value="chrome" />
       <parameter name="environment"  value="qa"/>
       <classes>
           <class name="tests.E2ETests">
           </class>
       </classes>
   </test>

  <test name="Web chrome tests2" enabled="true">
       <parameter name="deviceName" value="PCChrome" />
       <parameter name="platformType" value="mac" />
       <parameter name="browserName" value="chrome" />
       <parameter name="environment"  value="qa"/>
       <classes>
           <class name="tests.E2ETests">
           </class>
       </classes>
   </test>
</suite> ```


Just to clarify. Have you automated "an application which support desktop" with selenium ?

yes, desktop browser (chrome) using selenium webdriver, which is running fine, having issues while running in parallel

Let me add more clear, when we run 2 or more tests in parallel then only one test will run till end of the test and other tests open browsers and navigates to the home page from there they will not run and will stay idle state. sometimes all other browsers will get closed, so we can see only one test run instead of 2 or more in parallel

Can I expect any solution ?
